# Javascript RegExp Result

Tags: javascript, regex

If you use the regular expression `/(this|a)/`

Now if I have:

```
var text = "this is a sentence.";
text = text.replace(/(this|a)/gi, "_");
document.write(text);
```

I get the output: `_ is _ sentence`

I am working on a piece of Javascript that does selective styling so what I want to do is add `'<span class="className">" + word_in_regex + "</span>"` where `word_in_regex` is the word from the expression that has been matched. Is this possible or no?

Comment: Funny, the output you should have gotten with that regex is "_ is a sentence."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$1` in the replacement string to reference the match of the first group:

```
"this is a sentence".replace(/(this|a)/g, "_$1_")  // returns "_this_ is _a_ sentence"
```

Note the *g* flag to replace globally; otherwise only the first match will be replaced. See [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for further information.

Comment: Wow I didn't realize I left off the g. But this works exactly as needed.